# Angular ui router optional query param load the controller twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to have in some pages ui sref with optional param, but the problem is when i dont pass the param to ui sref its loading the controller twice. 
I want to have a optional query param. There is a better way to do this?

```
$stateProvider
        .state('play', {
          url        : "/lottery/:id/:isFree",
          controller : "myController",
          templateUrl: "client/play/index.html"
        });


ui-sref="play({id: game.id, isFree:4}) // this is working fine.

ui-sref="play({id: game.id}) // this is reloading the controller twice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed now. Try [this working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8xMqSWxZJ5seT83Ounb6?p=preview), which uses the latest **0.2.13** version

```
<script data-require="ui-router@*" 
    src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.13/release/angular-ui-router.js"
></script>
```

The issue can be reproduced in older versions, e.g. 0.2.8 *(not sure which versionn fixed that)*. There is a link to ["broken" plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/umjHlrpLUEeme3YZQa72?p=preview)

```
<script data-require="ui-router@*" 
    src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.8/release/angular-ui-router.js"
></script>
```